# WP CLI edit post refresh webpage without having to close file

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I am new to working with WP CLI but finding it to be a helpful tool so far.  I have found that if I work on a theme file in VIM and save the file, I can refresh the webpage run through local server and the updated code will be reflected.  If I use WP Edit on a page and do the same, the updated code will not reflect on the page.  Instead, I must close the file in order to have the updated code be reflected on the website.  I guess this has to do with the pages being in the DB rather than a theme file, but I am curious if there is a way to make it work more like theme files.  While not a big deal to close and re-open the file, it would be nice to save that step.  I have searched the inter-webs and also searched on stack, but unable to find an answer to this question.  I have also searched on the WP CLI documentation for posts and didn't see any commands that looked to accomplish this.  Please and thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, using `wp post edit 123` writes the post content to a temp file, launches a _blocking_ editor to edit the file, and finally upon close reads from the temp file and writes back to the database. Unfortunately there is no attempt at looking for signals such as “save”, probably because it is non-uniform. TBH, I’ve used the CLI extensively, and have even contributed to it on several occasions, but I didn’t know this feature even existed, and I can’t imagine using it much, if ever, in the real world. No judgment, just my opinion.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I know it's not a big deal, but would save a step from having to close and re-open the file every time I make an update and want to see the result.  I've seen lots of local servers that provide live-reloading features, so I'm a bit surprised that the WP CLI doesn't have this option available.  I guess every environment has its own characteristics.  Cheers!